# Why MySQL implicitly convert no data to empty string?

Tags: mysql, string, null

Lets create table

`` CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `data1` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    `data2` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ``

and paste some data

`` INSERT INTO `test` (`data1`) VALUES ('111'); ``

We did not specify `data2` but row have been inserted. Value of field `data2` is empty string. Why insertion didn't fail? Is it a bug?

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.19, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)

Comment: what is your sql_mode is set to? 
you can find that by checking this `show variables like 'sql_mode'` your sql_mode probably is set to empty which allows that. but you would get a warning.

Comment: sql_mode in my system is NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION. Only one variable found. It's default config - I have not changed anything since the installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your sql_mode does not contains `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` which will allow the insert to be executed and you will get a warning instead of an error..

You can check your sql_mode variable like so

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';
```

If you don't want that behavior you can change your sql_mode like so

```
-- change sql_mode only for the current session
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

and if you want this change to affect your entire server then

```
-- change the sql_mode for the entire server.
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

If you want to change it for the entire server. Then you also need to add update your my.ini file

look for the line that starts with `sql-mode =`

and replace it with

```
sql-mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

Updating my.ini file will prevent the server from reverting back after a reboot.

Comment: sql_mode on my system is NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION. there is only one value. It's default mysql config

Comment: Okay change it like I mentioned above and this will give you the desired outcome.

Comment: cool, I just updated the line to look for in your my.ini file if you want to change the mode for the entire server.